# Get third control point quadratic Bezier curve for parabola with given fucus and directrix, Lua

Tags: math, lua, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make the quadatic Bezier curve that is equivalent to the given parabola, that was defined as focus (fx, fy) and directrix dirY. (algorithm to make Voronoi diagram with sweeping line, the Fortune's algorithm)

The curve is limited by points A (ax, ay) and B (bx, by).

I need to find the third control point C (cx, cy) as here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quadratic_Bezier_parabola_equivalence.svg
or
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Relationship_between_parabola_and_quadratic_Bezier.svg

```
function getBezierControlPoint_focus_directrix(fx, fy, ax, ay, bx, by)
    -- (x-h)^2=4*p*(y-k)
    if (ay == by) then
        -- exception: horizontal AB
        local k = (fy + dirY) / 2
        local h = fx
        local cx = h
        local cy = ay + 2*(k-ay)
        return cx, cy -- it works perfect
    else
--  [Axis direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Axis_direction)
        local h = fx
        local k = (fy + dirY) / 2
        local cx = (ax+bx)/2
        local f = (k-dirY)/2
        
        -- vertex
        -- h = -b/(2*a)
        -- k = (4*a*c-b*b)/(4*a)
        
        local a = -1/(dirY-ay)
        local b = -2 * a * h
        local c = h * h * a + k
        print ('h', h, -b/(2*a)) -- ok, same
        print ('k', k, (4*a*c-b*b)/(4*a)) -- ok, same
        
        -- derivative value of parabola in point A (ax):
        local day = a*2*ax + b
        local cy = ay + day * (bx-ax)/2
        
        return cx, cy -- not right, here is problem
    end
end
```

usage: three control points to draw parabola:

```
controlPoints = {ax, ay, cx, cy, bx, by}
```

[image: Parabola as beach line, drawn with bezier-curve]

Parabola as beach line, drawn with bezier-curve
Update:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/joeugogi8b

Ready function:

```lua
function getBezierControlPoint (fx, fy, ax, bx)
    local function f(x) return (x*x-2*fx*x+fx*fx+fy*fy-dirY*dirY) / (2*(fy-dirY)) end
    local function df(x) return (x-fx) / (fy-dirY) end
    if (fy == dirY) then return end -- not parabola
    local ay, by = f(ax), f(bx)
    local ad, dx = df(ax), (bx-ax)/2
    local cx, cy = ax+dx, ay+ad*dx
    return cx, cy
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a focus **x=a,y=b** and directrix **y=c**, then we're already axis-aligned, so that saves a bunch of work.

A focus/directrix definition of the parabola is based on distance equivalences, so let's see which distances we can find for the "tip" **x,y** of the parabola:

1. `dist((x,y), (a,b))` = `sqrt((x-a)² + (y-b)²)`, and
2. `dist((x,y), (x,c))` = `abs(y - c)`

Easy enough, we can solve the equality `sqrt((x-a)² + (y-b)²) = abs(y - c)` (either by hand or by using something like wolfram alpha) and get:

```
        x² - 2ax + a² + b² -c²
f(x) = -----------------------
               2(b-c)
```

which in lua is:

```lua
function f(x, a, b, c)
    local n = x*x - 2*a*x + a*a + b*b - c*c
    local d = 2*(b-c)
    return n / d
end
```

(and we're ignoring what happens when `b==c`, because we'll never *call* this function if that is the case, because if the focus lies *on* the directrix, that's not a parabola)

Which means we now have a trivial-to-implement function for getting y=f(x) given any values **a**, **b**, and **c**, as long as **b** and **c** are not the same value.

We then want to find the equivalent Bezier expression for the segment with end points **A=(xa,f(xa))** and **B=(xb,f(xb))**, which means we're "done" already: for any quadratic Bezier curve, the control point lies at the intersection of the tangent line at the start, and the tangent line at the end of the segment.

Also note that we *do not get a choice* in what **ay** and **by** are: you only get to pick **ax** and **bx**, because **f(x)** defines what the corresponding **ay** and **by** *must* be.

Now, we (implicitly) know what the tangent lines are, because we know the derivative of **f(x)** (again, either because we worked that out by hand, or we just told a computer to do it for us):

```
        x-a
f'(x) = ---
        b-c
```

which in lua is:

```lua
function df(x, a, b, c)
    return (x-a) / (b-c)
end
```

And so finding that control point is a matter of calculating a standard line/line intersection, because you know **A** and the tangent at **A**, and we know **B** and the tangent at **B**. Lots of posts on Stackoverflow and pages on the web that explain how to calculate a line/line intersection, but let's use this one:

```lua
function lli(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)
    -- compact this as much as you feel the need to: lots of repeating values.
    local nx = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    local ny = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)
    local d = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)

    if (d == 0) then
        error("these lines don't intersect")
    end

    return { nx / d, ny / d}
end
```

And with that, we have everything we need:

```lua
function fdParabolaToBezier(a, b, c, ax, bx)
    if (b == c) then
        error("this is not a parabola")
    end

    -- y coordinate for A:
    local ay = f(ax, a, b, c)

    -- tangent slope for A:
    local ad = df(ax, a, b, c)

    -- y coordinate for B:
    local by = f(bx, a, b, c)

    -- tangent slope for B:
    local bd = df(bx, a, b, c)

    -- and then the tangent intersection:
    local C = lli(
        ax, ay,          -- A, which by definition lies on A's tangent
        ax + 1, ay + ad, -- The point on A's tangent at x=ax+1
        bx, by,          -- B, which by definition lies on B's tangent
        bx + a, by + bd  -- The point on B's tangent at x=ab+1
    )

    return {ax, ay, C[1], C[2], bx, by}
end
```

And then an example call for getting the Bezier equivalent of the curve segment on a parabola with focus (2,5) and directrix y=3, starting at x=-5 and ending at x=4:

```lua
local coords = fdParabolaToBezier(2, 5, 3, -5, 4)
print(table.concat(coords, ', '))
```

Which yields `-5, 16.25, 6.9117647058824, 7.9117647058824, 4, 5.0`

Comment: Thanks, now I see that I need to calculate cx = ax+dx and cy = ay+dx*ad, where ad is tangent in the point A.

Comment: `function df(x, a, b, c) return (x-a) / (b-x) end` is wrong: must be `function df(x, a, b, c) return (x-a) / (b-c) end`

Comment: ah, good typo find. Fixed in the post.